# Erro SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um Jogo "Pedra, Papel e tesoura", estou no momento final, mas meu código está com um erro que não consigo identificar.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Voce escolhe pedra, papel ou tesoura?");
var computerChoice = Math.random(1);
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "pedra";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "papel";
} else {
    computerChoice = "tesoura";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function (choice1, choice2){
if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return "O resultado e um empate";
}

else if(choice1 === "pedra") {

    if(choice2 === "tesoura") {
        return "pedra vence";
    }
    else {
        return "papel vence";
    }

}

else if(choice1 === "papel") {

    if(choice2 === "pedra")
        return "papel vence";
    }
    else {
        return "tesoura vence";
    };

else if(choice1 === "tesoura") {
    if(choice2 === "pedra")
        return "papel vence";
    };
};
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? O que você esperava que acontecesse, e o que de fato acontece?

Comment: Obg pela atenção, então eu tenho que criar um jogo "pedra, papel e tesoura", daí por prompt vou perguntar ao user (jogador) qual ele escolhe, da crio um Macht.random me dando um valor randômico de 0 a 1, dai defino um valor exemplo 0.34 = pedra, por fim vem a parte onde a disputa acontece, onde o jogador defini quem ganha ou perde, utilizado o if else com outro if else dentro, mas na hora de executar da o seguinte erro: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else"

Comment: Recomendo fazer titulos mais descritivos amigo e só use os snippets se for adicionar um exemplo para execução.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pelas recomendações, eu sou novo aqui, logo, ainda estou aprendendo.

Answer (score 5):

O problema parece ser aqui:

```
…
else if(choice1 === "papel") {

    if(choice2 === "pedra")
        return "papel vence";
    }
    else {
        return "tesoura vence";
    };

else if(choice1 === "tesoura") {
…
```

Se você prestar atenção, você nunca fecha o `else if(choice1 === "papel") {` — no `else if(choice1 === "pedra") {` logo acima você colocou o `}`, mas nesse não.

(O `;` no `};` é desnecessário, mas não faz diferença pro seu código.)

Comment: Parece ser isto mesmo +1, talvez pude-se recomendar switchs e callbacks (não precisaria de exemplos em cima do código, apenas links para estudo, pois ao meu ver você já respondeu muito bem a pergunta) :)

Comment: É uma opção, mas note que acontecem coisas estranhas se o usuário jogar e.g. `PEDRA` ou `tigre`… consertar isso seria reescrever o código, essencialmente; eu acho preciosismo colocar o `switch (…) {…}` sem fazer esses ajustes.

Comment: A ideia não era você adicionar isto ao código, apenas indicar boas leituras para outras praticas, não ligadas ao códigos, mas ao "aprendizado do autor" sobre ifs, switchs e funções. Mas realmente pode confundi-lo. Melhor deixar como está :)